# Powershell Try Catch Multiple User Inputs and when both are correct Apply Teams Policies

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

#Beginner# Trying to write a PowerShell script that needs to verify multiple User inputs first before applying policies. This is for MS Teams. Prompt User to enter UserID, Check if User is Correct in MS Teams Tenant. If and When the UserID is correct then Check the input for the Phone Number (This is in a table form in the script). [If there was a way to verify Active Directory if the User's Phone is correct even better!]. If and When the Telephone Format is correct, then and only then Apply all the relevant policies to the UserID.

Currently, it does check the User ID and Phone Number Format but Does Not Apply the Policies. It states you have entered an invalid User ID and prompts you to check for another User. Instead of applying the policies.

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve]

[image: This is the Results and error after executing script]

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

do {
  try {
    $upnentry = Read-Host 'Enter the User Principle Name'
    # if the UPN is invalid, this errors and goes to the `catch` block
    $csu = Get-CsOnlineUser -Identity $upnentry -ErrorAction Stop
    # if the above didn't error, then we're here, hence display to console
    $csu | Format-List IsSipEnabled, Displ*
    Write-Host 'User ID has been verified correctly!' -ForegroundColor Green
    $phoneinputblock = {
      try
      {
         [validatescript({[regex]::Match($_,'^44\d{10}$').Length -eq 12})]
         $phoneUserInput = Read-Host "`nEnter User's Telephone Number "
         $phoneUserInput
      }
      catch
      {
         Write-Warning "Incorrect Format for Telephone Number!"
         & $phoneinputBlock
      }
    }
    $phoneuserInput = & $phoneinputBlock
    Write-Host 'Telephone Number is in the correct format!'
    Write-Host 'Estimated time to apply policies is the 20s!' -ForegroundColor Magenta

    Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment -Identity $user -PhoneNumber $phonenumberinput - 
     PhoneNumberType DirectRouting
     Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -PolicyName VRP-International -Identity $upnentry
     Grant-CsCallingLineIdentity -PolicyName CIDP-Global-Users-Number  -Identity $upnentry
     Grant-CSTenantDialPlan -policyname DP-All-Users -identity  $upnentry


     Write-host "Policies applied successfully for : $upnentry"  -ForegroundColor Green
     Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
     Write-host "`printing policies that have been applied to User: "  -ForegroundColor Green
     Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
     Get-CsOnlineUser $upnentry | Format-List IsSipEnabled, Displ*, UserPri*, SipA*, 
       LineURI, TeamsUpgradeE*, Enterprise*, 
       TenantD*,  Feature*, AssignedPlan, OnlineVoiceR*, OnlineAudio*, TeamsCall*, 
     CallingLine*, TeamsEmergency
  }
  catch {
    # display this warning if failed and ask to check other profile
    Write-Warning "You've entered an invalid UserID. $upnentry"
  }
} until($Host.UI.PromptForChoice('', 'Do you want to check another Users Profile?', ('&Yes', '&No'), 0))
```

Comment: Have you checked that the user is created on Teams also. Although the user was created in Azure, but it is taking time to be created in Teams.

Comment: Hi Nivedipa, THanks for responding. I'm not sure I understand your statement correctly but To provide more information. The Users are already imported into Teams. They don't have telephone numbers assigned to them, Hence the script will check that the username (UPN) entered is correctly and exists in the Tenant (or via a .csv file that contains hundreds of Users), then checks the format of the number entered and if both are correct then apply the policies.

Comment: What is the deault fail type of the inner try? If it doesn't generate a Stop error, it won't be triggered.

Comment: @Dillon - Could you please share the details whichever Dennis has asked?